# how to print field in chinese in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, encoding, pymongo

I have an `extracted_text` field in each document and the value of `extracted_text` is some chinese text. when I want to print the `extracted_text` field the program encountered a run-time error. I know MongoDB store strings as `utf-8`,  but my program failed to encode `extracted_text` in `gbk`.

I tried some other decode encode combination and they all are wrong. I think I have grasped the knowledge of encode/decode of python, but this error made me confused. so could you please point out what's wrong with my program.

Thanks!

Below is my program and the output log.

```
#encoding=gbk
from pymongo import MongoClient
import bson

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db=client.jd
pages=db.pages
for page in pages.find():
    print page
    for key in page:
        print "1, key", key 
        print "2, key type", type(page[key])
        if page[key] is None:
            print key+"\t"+"None"
        elif type(page[key]) is unicode:
            print key +"\t"+  page[key].encode('gbk', 'ignore')
```

the output

```
{u'url': u'http://item.jd.com/1635670097.html', u'_id': ObjectId('5656815e4a487a1735aadbae'), u'extracted_text': u'\t\t\tPlover\u5544\u6728\u9e1f \u771f\u76ae\u76ae\u978b \u5546\u52a1\u4f11\u95f2\u978b\u900f\u6c14\u7537\u58eb\u5934\u5c42\u725b\u76ae\u590f\u5b63\u8212\u9002\u5957\u811a\u8f6f\u5e95\u82f1\u4f26\u5a5a\u978b\u6b63\u88c5\u978b\u5b50 \u9ed1\u8272 40\u3010\u56fe\u7247 \u4ef7\u683c \u54c1\u724c \u62a5\u4ef7\u3011-\u4eac\u4e1c\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u6536\u85cf\u4eac\u4e1c\t\t\t\t\t\t\u60a8\u597d\uff01\u6b22\u8fce\u6765\u5230\u4eac\u4e1c\uff01\t\t\t\t\t\t\t[\u767b\u5f55]\t\t\t\t\t\t\t[\u514d\u8d39\u6ce8\u518c]\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u6211\u7684\u8ba2\u5355\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4eac\u4e1c\u4f1a\u5458\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u624b\u673a\u4eac\u4e1c\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5ba2\u6237\u670d\u52a1\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5e2e\u52a9\u4e2d\u5fc3\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u552e\u540e\u670d\u52a1\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5728\u7ebf\u5ba2\u670d\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u610f\u89c1\u5efa\u8bae\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5ba2\u670d\u90ae\u7bb1\t\t\t\t\t\t\u7f51\u7ad9\u5bfc\u822a\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u7279\u8272\u680f\u76ee\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4eac\u4e1c\u901a\u4fe1\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u6821\u56ed\u4e4b\u661f\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4e3a\u6211\u63a8\u8350\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u89c6\u9891\u8d2d\u7269\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4eac\u4e1c\u793e\u533a\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5728\u7ebf\u8bfb\u4e66\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u88c5\u673a\u5927\u5e08\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4eac\u4e1cE\u5361\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5bb6\u88c5\u57ce\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u642d\u914d\u8d2d\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u6211\u559c\u6b22\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4f01\u4e1a\u670d\u52a1\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4f01\u4e1a\u5ba2\u6237\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u529e\u516c\u76f4\u901a\u8f66\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u65d7\u4e0b\u7f51\u7ad9\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tEnglish Site\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u66f4\u591a\u5bfc\u822a\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u670d\u88c5\u57ce\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u98df\u54c1\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u56e2\u8d2d\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u593a\u5b9d\u5c9b\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u95ea\u8d2d\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u91d1\u878d\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u70ed\u95e8\u641c\u7d22\uff1a\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u51ac\u5b63\u8fde\u8863\u88d9\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u8fd0\u52a8\u7fbd\u7ed2\u670d\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u7bb1\u5305\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4fdd\u6696\u5185\u8863\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u51b2\u950b\u8863\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u7cbe\u54c1\u7537\u88c5\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u7f51\u4e0a\u914d\u955c\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u56f4\u5dfe\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u6211\u7684\u4eac\u4e1c\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u60a8\u597d\uff0c\u8bf7\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u767b\u5f55\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5f85\u5904\u7406\u8ba2\u5355\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u54a8\u8be2\u56de\u590d\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u964d\u4ef7\u5546\u54c1\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u8fd4\u4fee\u9000\u6362\u8d27\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4f18\u60e0\u5238\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u6211\u7684\u5173\u6ce8\xa0>\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u6211\u7684\u4eac\u8c46\xa0>\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u6211\u7684\u7406\u8d22\xa0>\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u6211\u7684\u767d\u6761\xa0>\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4eac\u4e1c\u91d1\u91c7\xa0>\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u6700\u8fd1\u6d4f\u89c8\u7684\u5546\u54c1\uff1a\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u67e5\u770b\u6d4f\u89c8\u5386\u53f2\xa0>\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t14\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u53bb\u8d2d\u7269\u8f66\u7ed3\u7b97\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u8d2d\u7269\u8f66\u4e2d\u8fd8\u6ca1\u6709\u5546\u54c1\uff0c\u8d76\u7d27\u9009\u8d2d\u5427\uff01\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u978b\u9774\t\t\t\t\t\t\xa0>\xa0\t\t\t\t\t\t\xa0>\xa0\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPlover\u5544\u6728\u9e1f \u771f\u76ae\u76ae\u978b \u5546\u52a1\u4f11\u95f2\u978b\u900f\u6c14\u7537\u58eb\u5934\u5c42\u725b\u76ae\u590f\u5b63..\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5546\u54c1\u7f16\u53f7\uff1a\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t1635670097\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5173\u6ce8\u5546\u54c1\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5206\u4eab\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPlover\u5544\u6728\u9e1f \u771f\u76ae\u76ae\u978b \u5546\u52a1\u4f11\u95f2\u978b\u900f\u6c14\u7537\u58eb\u5934\u5c42\u725b\u76ae\u590f\u5b63\u8212\u9002\u5957\u811a\u8f6f\u5e95\u82f1\u4f26\u5a5a\u978b\u6b63\u88c5\u978b\u5b50 \u9ed1\u8272 40\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u7d2f\u8ba1\u8bc4\u4ef7\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4eac \u4e1c \u4ef7\uff1a\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(\u964d\u4ef7\u901a\u77e5)\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4fc3\u9500\u4fe1\u606f\uff1a\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u9879\u4fc3\u9500\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u652f\u3000\u3000\u6301\uff1a\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u914d \u9001 \u81f3\uff1a\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u670d\u3000\u3000\u52a1\uff1a\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u9009\u62e9\u989c\u8272\uff1a\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u9ed1\u8272\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u68d5\u8272\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u9009\u62e9\u5c3a\u7801\uff1a\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t38\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t39\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t40\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t41\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t42\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t43\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t44\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u76ae\u978b\u7801 \u6bd4\u8fd0\u52a8\u978b\u5927\u4e00\u7801\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5408\u7ea6\u5957\u9910\uff1a\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u9009\u62e9\u5957\u9910\u4e0e\u8d44\u8d39\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u8bf7\u9009\u62e9\u5957\u9910\u5185\u5bb9\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u91cd\u9009\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u3000\u60a8\u9009\u62e9\u7684\u5730\u533a\u6682\u4e0d\u652f\u6301\u5408\u7ea6\u673a\u9500\u552e\uff01\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u62a2\u8d2d\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u9009\u4f5c\u793c\u7269\u8d2d\u4e70\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u9009\u62e9\u53f7\u7801\u548c\u5957\u9910\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u52a0\u5165\u8d2d\u7269\u8f66\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u6253\u767d\u6761\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5230\u8d27\u901a\u77e5\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u6e29\u99a8\u63d0\u793a\uff1a\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u66f4\u591a\u5546\u54c1\u4fe1\u606f\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4e50\u54c1\u6c47\u978b\u9774\u4e13\u8425\u5e97\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u7efc\u5408\u8bc4\u5206\uff1a\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5206\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u7ec6\u5219\u8bc4\u5206\uff1a\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t9.96\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t9.68\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t9.96\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u7efc\u5408\u8bc4\u5206\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u8bc4\u5206\u7ec6\u5219\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u76f8\u6bd4\u884c\u4e1a\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t9.8\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5546\u54c1\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t9.96\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t70.7%\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u670d\u52a1\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t9.68\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t9.80%\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u65f6\u6548\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t9.96\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t55.6%\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u516c\u53f8\u540d\u79f0\uff1a\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u8386\u7530\u5e02\u4e50\u54c1\u6c47\u8d38\u6613\u6709\u9650\u516c\u53f8\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u6240 \u5728 \u5730\uff1a\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u798f\u5efa \u8386\u7530\u5e02\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5728\u7ebf\u5ba2\u670d\uff1a\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u8fdb\u5165\u5e97\u94fa\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5173\u6ce8\u5e97\u94fa\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u670d\u52a1\u652f\u6301\uff1a\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u63a8\u8350\u914d\u4ef6\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4f18\u60e0\u5957\u88c5\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u6700\u4f73\u7ec4\u5408\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u52a0\u8f7d\u4e2d\uff0c\u8bf7\u7a0d\u5019...\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u52a0\u8f7d\u4e2d\uff0c\u8bf7\u7a0d\u5019...\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u52a0\u8f7d\u4e2d\uff0c\u8bf7\u7a0d\u5019...\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5546\u54c1\u4ecb\u7ecd\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5546\u54c1\u8bc4\u4ef7\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(0)\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u552e\u540e\u4fdd\u969c\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4eac\u4e1c\u670d\u52a1\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u52a0\u5165\u8d2d\u7269\u8f66\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPlover\u5544\u6728\u9e1f \u771f\u76ae\u76ae\u978b \u5546\u52a1\u4f11\u95f2\u978b\u900f\u6c14\u7537\u58eb\u5934\u5c42\u725b\u76ae\u590f\u5b63\u8212\u9002\u5957\u811a\u8f6f\u5e95\u82f1\u4f26\u5a5a\u978b\u6b63\u88c5\u978b\u5b50 \u9ed1\u8272 40\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4eac\u4e1c\u4ef7\uff1a\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5ba2\u6237\u7aef\u9996\u5355 \u6ee179\u900179\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u52a0\u8f7d\u4e2d\uff0c\u8bf7\u7a0d\u5019...\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5546\u54c1\u540d\u79f0\uff1aPlover\u5544\u6728\u9e1f \u771f\u76ae\u76ae\u978b \u5546\u52a1\u4f11\u95f2\u978b\u900f\u6c14\u7537\u58eb\u5934\u5c42\u725b\u76ae\u590f\u5b63\u8212\u9002\u5957\u811a\u8f6f\u5e95\u82f1\u4f26\u5a5a\u978b\u6b63\u88c5\u978b\u5b50 \u9ed1\u8272 40\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5546\u54c1\u7f16\u53f7\uff1a1635670097\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5e97\u94fa\uff1a\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4e50\u54c1\u6c47\u978b\u9774\u4e13\u8425\u5e97\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4e0a\u67b6\u65f6\u95f4\uff1a2015-07-14 17:59:42\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5546\u54c1\u6bdb\u91cd\uff1a1.25kg\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u8d27\u53f7\uff1a8175\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5c3a\u7801\uff1a38\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u9500\u552e\u6e20\u9053\u7c7b\u578b\uff1a\u7ebf\u4e0a\u9500\u552e\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u98ce\u683c\uff1a\u82f1\u4f26\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u978b\u9762\u6750\u6599\uff1a\u5934\u5c42\u725b\u76ae\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u6d41\u884c\u5143\u7d20\uff1a\u8f66\u7f1d\u7ebf\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u989c\u8272\uff1a\u9ed1\u8272\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u76ae\u9769\u98ce\u683c\uff1a\u8f6f\u9762\u76ae\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4e0a\u5e02\u5e74\u4efd\u5b63\u8282\uff1a2015\u79cb\u5b63\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u978b\u5e95\u6750\u8d28\uff1a\u6a61\u80f6\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u95ed\u5408\u65b9\u5f0f\uff1a\u5957\u811a\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u978b\u8ddf\uff1a\u6709\u8ddf\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u529f\u80fd\uff1a\u8010\u78e8\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u978b\u5934\u6b3e\u5f0f\uff1a\u5706\u5934\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u91cc\u6599\u6750\u8d28\uff1a\u76ae\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t249\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u51ac\u5b63\u9ad8\u5e2e\u677f\u978b\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t268\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u6237\u5916\u4f11\u95f2\u76ae\u978b\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t268\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u65f6\u5c1a\u4fdd\u6696\u7537\u9774\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t199\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u65b0\u6b3e\u7cfb\u5e26\u7537\u978b\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t249\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u6b63\u88c5\u9632\u6ed1\u76ae\u978b\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t278\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u8f6f\u5e95\u8212\u9002\u6b63\u88c5\u978b\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5982\u679c\u60a8\u53d1\u73b0\u5546\u54c1\u4fe1\u606f\u4e0d\u51c6\u786e\uff0c\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u6b22\u8fce\u7ea0\u9519\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5546\u54c1\u4ecb\u7ecd\u52a0\u8f7d\u4e2d...\t\t\t\t\t\t\u6ce8\uff1a\u56e0\u5382\u5bb6\u4f1a\u5728\u6ca1\u6709\u4efb\u4f55\u63d0\u524d\u901a\u77e5\u7684\u60c5\u51b5\u4e0b\u66f4\u6539\u4ea7\u54c1\u5305\u88c5\u3001\u4ea7\u5730\u6216\u8005\u4e00\u4e9b\u9644\u4ef6\uff0c\u672c\u53f8\u4e0d\u80fd\u786e\u4fdd\u5ba2\u6237\u6536\u5230\u7684\u8d27\u7269\u4e0e\u5546\u57ce\u56fe\u7247\u3001\u4ea7\u5730\u3001\u9644\u4ef6\u8bf4\u660e\u5b8c\u5168\u4e00\u81f4\u3002\u53ea\u80fd\u786e\u4fdd\u4e3a\u539f\u5382\u6b63\u8d27\uff01\u5e76\u4e14\u4fdd\u8bc1\u4e0e\u5f53\u65f6\u5e02\u573a\u4e0a\u540c\u6837\u4e3b\u6d41\u65b0\u54c1\u4e00\u81f4\u3002\u82e5\u672c\u5546\u57ce\u6ca1\u6709\u53ca\u65f6\u66f4\u65b0\uff0c\u8bf7\u5927\u5bb6\u8c05\u89e3\uff01\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4eac\u4e1c\u4e0a\u7684\u6240\u6709\u5546\u54c1\u4fe1\u606f\u3001\u5ba2\u6237\u8bc4\u4ef7\u3001\u5546\u54c1\u54a8\u8be2\u3001\u7f51\u53cb\u8ba8\u8bba\u7b49\u5185\u5bb9\uff0c\u662f\u4eac\u4e1c\u91cd\u8981\u7684\u7ecf\u8425\u8d44\u6e90\uff0c\u672a\u7ecf\u8bb8\u53ef\uff0c\u7981\u6b62\u975e\u6cd5\u8f6c\u8f7d\u4f7f\u7528\u3002\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u672c\u7ad9\u5546\u54c1\u4fe1\u606f\u5747\u6765\u81ea\u4e8e\u5408\u4f5c\u65b9\uff0c\u5176\u771f\u5b9e\u6027\u3001\u51c6\u786e\u6027\u548c\u5408\u6cd5\u6027\u7531\u4fe1\u606f\u62e5\u6709\u8005\uff08\u5408\u4f5c\u65b9\uff09\u8d1f\u8d23\u3002\u672c\u7ad9\u4e0d\u63d0\u4f9b\u4efb\u4f55\u4fdd\u8bc1\uff0c\u5e76\u4e0d\u627f\u62c5\u4efb\u4f55\u6cd5\u5f8b\u8d23\u4efb\u3002\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5370\u5237\u7248\u6b21\u4e0d\u540c\uff0c\u5370\u5237\u65f6\u95f4\u548c\u7248\u6b21\u4ee5\u5b9e\u7269\u4e3a\u51c6\u3002\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5546\u54c1\u8bc4\u4ef7\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u52a0\u8f7d\u4e2d\uff0c\u8bf7\u7a0d\u5019...\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5168\u90e8\u8bc4\u4ef7\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t()\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u597d\u8bc4\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t()\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4e2d\u8bc4\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t()\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5dee\u8bc4\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t()\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u6709\u56fe\u7247\u7684\u8bc4\u4ef7\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t()\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u52a0\u8f7d\u4e2d\uff0c\u8bf7\u7a0d\u5019...\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u52a0\u8f7d\u4e2d\uff0c\u8bf7\u7a0d\u5019...\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u52a0\u8f7d\u4e2d\uff0c\u8bf7\u7a0d\u5019...\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u52a0\u8f7d\u4e2d\uff0c\u8bf7\u7a0d\u5019...\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u52a0\u8f7d\u4e2d\uff0c\u8bf7\u7a0d\u5019...\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5168\u90e8\u8d2d\u4e70\u54a8\u8be2\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5546\u54c1\u54a8\u8be2\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5e93\u5b58\u914d\u9001\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u652f\u4ed8\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u53d1\u7968\u4fdd\u4fee\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u53d6\u6d88\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u56e0\u5382\u5bb6\u66f4\u6539\u4ea7\u54c1\u5305\u88c5\u3001\u4ea7\u5730\u6216\u8005\u66f4\u6362\u968f\u673a\u9644\u4ef6\u7b49\u6ca1\u6709\u4efb\u4f55\u63d0\u524d\u901a\u77e5\uff0c\u4e14\u6bcf\u4f4d\u54a8\u8be2\u8005\u8d2d\u4e70\u60c5\u51b5\u3001\u63d0\u95ee\u65f6\u95f4\u7b49\u4e0d\u540c\uff0c\u4e3a\u6b64\u4ee5\u4e0b\u56de\u590d\u4ec5\u5bf9\u63d0\u95ee\u80053\u5929\u5185\u6709\u6548\uff0c\u5176\u4ed6\u7f51\u53cb\u4ec5\u4f9b\u53c2\u8003\uff01\u82e5\u7531\u6b64\u7ed9\u60a8\u5e26\u6765\u4e0d\u4fbf\u8bf7\u591a\u591a\u8c05\u89e3\uff0c\u8c22\u8c22\uff01\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u52a0\u8f7d\u4e2d\uff0c\u8bf7\u7a0d\u5019...\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u52a0\u8f7d\u4e2d\uff0c\u8bf7\u7a0d\u5019...\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u52a0\u8f7d\u4e2d\uff0c\u8bf7\u7a0d\u5019...\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u52a0\u8f7d\u4e2d\uff0c\u8bf7\u7a0d\u5019...\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u52a0\u8f7d\u4e2d\uff0c\u8bf7\u7a0d\u5019...\t\t\t\t\t\t\u9500\u552e\u8054\u76df\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4eac\u4e1c\u516c\u76ca\t\t\t\t\t\t\u53cb\u60c5\u94fe\u63a5\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u6d3e\u5199\u9e4f\u4ef6\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(\u5317\u4eac)\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2015-11-23\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u8d28\u91cf\u4e0d\u9519\uff0c\u505a\u5de5..\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2015-11-23 19:10:50\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4f7f\u7528\u5fc3\u5f97\uff1a\u8d28\u91cf\u4e0d\u9519\uff0c\u505a\u5de5..\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u83c1\u9999\u5bfb\u5ffb\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(\u6e56\u5317)\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2015-11-23\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5c3a\u7801\u521a\u5408\u811a\uff0c\u6837..\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2015-11-23 19:06:37\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4f7f\u7528\u5fc3\u5f97\uff1a\u5c3a\u7801\u521a\u5408\u811a\uff0c\u6837..\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u8a00\u9999\u99a8\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(\u6d59\u6c5f)\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2015-11-23\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u978b\u5b50\u8d28\u91cf\u5f88\u597d\uff0c..\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2015-11-23 19:02:09\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4f7f\u7528\u5fc3\u5f97\uff1a\u978b\u5b50\u8d28\u91cf\u5f88\u597d\uff0c..\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u7434\u56e0\u5415\u9edb\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(\u5317\u4eac)\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2015-11-23\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u7269\u6d41\u5f88\u5feb\u3002\u5305\u88c5..\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2015-11-23 18:59:47\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4f7f\u7528\u5fc3\u5f97\uff1a\u7269\u6d41\u5f88\u5feb\u3002\u5305\u88c5..\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u79f0\u658c\u7ef4\u67e5\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(\u5b89\u5fbd)\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2015-11-23\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u978b\u5b50\u6536\u5230\u4e86\uff0c\u8bd5..\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2015-11-23 18:57:23\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4f7f\u7528\u5fc3\u5f97\uff1a\u978b\u5b50\u6536\u5230\u4e86\uff0c\u8bd5..\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tkefkke1082\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(\u5b89\u5fbd)\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2015-11-23\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u978b\u5b50\u6536\u5230\u4e86\uff0c\u8bd5..\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2015-11-23 18:49:50\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4f7f\u7528\u5fc3\u5f97\uff1a\u978b\u5b50\u6536\u5230\u4e86\uff0c\u8bd5..\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tkuikui72863\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(\u5e7f\u4e1c)\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2015-11-22\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u978b\u5b50\uff0c\u6536\u5230\u4e86\uff0c..\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2015-11-22 19:41:24\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4f7f\u7528\u5fc3\u5f97\uff1a\u978b\u5b50\uff0c\u6536\u5230\u4e86\uff0c..\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tlangnhr368791\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(\u5e7f\u4e1c)\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2015-11-22\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u978b\u5b50\u8fd8\u662f\u5934\u4e00\u6b21..\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2015-11-22 19:37:13\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4f7f\u7528\u5fc3\u5f97\uff1a\u978b\u5b50\u8fd8\u662f\u5934\u4e00\u6b21..\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tntmcai3806\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(\u56db\u5ddd)\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2015-11-22\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u978b\u5b50\u9001\u7ed9\u8001\u516c\u7684..\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2015-11-22 19:32:54\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4f7f\u7528\u5fc3\u5f97\uff1a\u978b\u5b50\u9001\u7ed9\u8001\u516c\u7684..\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tdanddan322333\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(\u6d59\u6c5f)\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2015-11-21\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4eca\u5929\u770b\u5230\u54e5\u54e5\u5f88..\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t2015-11-21 19:42:17\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4f7f\u7528\u5fc3\u5f97\uff1a\u4eca\u5929\u770b\u5230\u54e5\u54e5\u5f88..\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u70ed\u95e8\u8d34\u5b50\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u7f51\u53cb\u8ba8\u8bba\u5708\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u6652\u5355\u8d34\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u8ba8\u8bba\u8d34\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u95ee\u7b54\u8d34\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5708\u5b50\u8d34\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u52a0\u8f7d\u4e2d\uff0c\u8bf7\u7a0d\u5019...\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u52a0\u8f7d\u4e2d\uff0c\u8bf7\u7a0d\u5019...\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u52a0\u8f7d\u4e2d\uff0c\u8bf7\u7a0d\u5019...\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u52a0\u8f7d\u4e2d\uff0c\u8bf7\u7a0d\u5019...\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u52a0\u8f7d\u4e2d\uff0c\u8bf7\u7a0d\u5019...\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u52a0\u8f7d\u4e2d\uff0c\u8bf7\u7a0d\u5019...\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u6d4f\u89c8\u4e86\u8be5\u5546\u54c1\u7684\u7528\u6237\u8fd8\u6d4f\u89c8\u4e86\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u52a0\u8f7d\u4e2d\uff0c\u8bf7\u7a0d\u5019...\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5e97\u5185\u641c\u7d22\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5173\u952e\u5b57\uff1a\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u4ef7\u3000\u683c\uff1a\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5230\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u3000\u3000\u3000\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5e97\u957f\u63a8\u8350\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5544\u6728\u9e1f(PLOVER)\u65b0\u6b3e\u65f6\u5c1a\u7537\u978b \u53cd\u7ed2\u76ae\u82f1\u4f26\u4f11\u95f2\u978b\u65f6\u5c1a\u677f\u978b\u7cfb\u5e26\u900f\u6c14\u6f6e\u6d41\u78e8\u7802\u5de5\u88c5\u978b\u6237\u5916\u978b\u5b50 \u84dd\u8272 38\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5544\u6728\u9e1f\u7537\u978b \u65b0\u6b3e\u7537\u58eb\u5546\u52a1\u4f11\u95f2\u978b\u97e9\u7248\u771f\u76ae\u7cfb\u5e26\u65f6\u5c1a\u677f\u978b \u82f1\u4f26\u6237\u5916\u7537\u58eb\u6f6e\u6d41\u4f4e\u5e2e\u61d2\u4eba\u978b\u5934\u5c42\u725b\u76ae\u978b \u767d\u8272 38\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5544\u6728\u9e1fPlover\u7537\u978b \u65b0\u6b3e\u590f\u5b63\u6237\u5916\u4f11\u95f2\u978b\u8fd0\u52a8\u978b\u900f\u6c14\u6f6e\u6d41\u7537\u58eb\u5355\u978b\u82f1\u4f26\u65f6\u5c1a\u767e\u642d\u97e9\u7248\u53cd\u7ed2\u76ae\u677f\u978b \u68d5\u8272 38\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPlover\u5544\u6728\u9e1f \u76ae\u978b \u5546\u52a1\u4f11\u95f2\u978b\u900f\u6c14\u7537\u58eb\u5934\u5c42\u725b\u76ae\u590f\u5b63\u8212\u9002\u5957\u811a\u8f6f\u5e95\u771f\u76ae\u82f1\u4f26\u5a5a\u978b\u6b63\u88c5\u978b\u5b50 \u9ed1\u8272 38\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPlover\u5544\u6728\u9e1f \u7537\u978b2015\u590f\u5b63\u65b0\u6b3e\u4f11\u95f2\u978b\u900f\u6c14\u6237\u5916\u9632\u6ed1\u677f\u978b \u7537\u58eb\u97e9\u7248\u65c5\u6e38\u978b\u9a7e\u8f66\u978b\u6f6e\u978b \u84dd\u8272 38\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\u5544\u6728\u9e1fPlover \u7537\u978b2015\u590f\u5b63\u65b0\u6b3e \u4f11\u95f2\u978b \u7537\u58eb\u82f1\u4f26\u65f6\u5c1a\u97e9\u7248\u677f\u978b \u6f6e\u6d41\u65e5\u5e38\u4f11\u95f2\u978b\u5b50 \u6df1\u84dd\u8272 38'}
1, key url
2, key type <type 'unicode'>
url http://item.jd.com/1635670097.html
1, key _id
2, key type <class 'bson.objectid.ObjectId'>
1, key extracted_text
2, key type <type 'unicode'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "query.py", line 16, in <module>
    print key +"\t"+  page[key].encode('gbk', 'ignore')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because the 'key' is unicode, you may try:

```
print key.encode('gbk', 'ignore') +"\t"+ page[key].encode('gbk', 'ignore')
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I didn't notice the type of `key`. it's awkward. Thanks